# SMTP Server design (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, email, server, smtp

I wanted to design my own SMTP server using an AWS Lightsail Linux instance, and I have my own domain name. I followed the documentation to set up the server, but encountered an issue: while I receive emails sent from Outlook or Gmail to my mail server, I am unable to send emails from my server to other SMTP servers like Google or Outlook. I need help resolving this issue, so if anyone can assist, please join the discussion and help me troubleshoot.

I tried to design smtp server and it was working perfectly and I was also getting emails from gmail or outlook these platform but when ever I tried to send mail from my smtp server for example if my domain is xyz.com then I was trying to send mail from support@xyz.com to any server (gmail, outlook) then I was not able to do this.